# How do I add a library to my NetBeans C++ project?

Tags: c++, boost, netbeans

I want to use the [boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) in order to use some of its functions but I don't know how to do so and cannot seem to find an answer.
I'm currently using NetBeans 8.0.1 ,any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add two things:

### (a) Library header

Go to …

**`Project Properties -> C++ Compiler -> Include Directories`**

add the header's *directory path* there.

### (b) Library binaries

Go to …

**`Project Properties -> Linker -> Additional Libraries Directory`**

and add the *directory path*- that's where your library binaries are.

Next add your library at:

**`Libraries`**.